# Keep connected Android app with a BLE device

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to ask for your valuable opinion about the following:

I'm developing an Android app that needs to connect with the BLE device (whose name I know) automatically on starting the app. Furthermore, the app should be able to keep the phone connected to the BLE device (there will be no "connect" and "disconnect" buttons on the app screen). In other words, if established connection is lost for some reason, the app should be capable to detect this and to re-connect again. The user of the app don't need to be aware of this background process. For him/her, it is only important that the phone is connected with the BLE device.

Simply speaking, I know the name of the BLE device (it is called 'HMSoft'). How should I keep the app connected with this BLE module? Should I use some Thread that will do the job for me in parallel with my other activities within the app MainActivity? Or there is some better approach? Did you have similar experience in the past?

Thank you very much for your time and effort. I really appreciate it.

Sincerely,
Bojan.

Answer (score 0):

You will want to wrap the BLE implementation up in a Service. Within that Service, you will have to implement the logic to connect to the BLE device and keep trying to connect to that BLE device if it becomes unavailable.

Comment: The link is dead.